# Monotonicity of the divergence

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Let $P, Q$ be probability measures on a measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$, and suppose $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $Q$. For any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$, we define
$$
D_{\mathcal G}(P \| Q) := \sum P(A) \log \frac{P(A)}{Q(A)}. 
$$
The sum above ranges over atoms $A \in \mathcal{G}$. I saw it claimed that $D_{\mathcal{H}}(P\|Q) \leq D_{\mathcal{G}}(P \|Q)$ provided $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra.

I can see this is true if for each atom $A$ of $\mathcal{H}$ there exists a collection $B_1, \dots, B_m$ in the atoms of $\mathcal{G}$ such that $A = \cup_i B_i$, and by the convexity of the function $t \mapsto t \log t$ (the so-called log-sum inequalities). In some simple examples this condition is true, but I am not sure if this true in general. I would be interested in any ideas people have to help establish this claim as I am struggling to prove it.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the data processing inequality?

Comment: @ClementC. So I think you can construct $P^\mathcal{G}, Q^\mathcal{G}$ that arise from a kernel relatively easily. But I think the goal was to prove this without using data processing (see Bucheron, Lugosi, Massart, exercise 4.10. They call this the "Data processing lemma", which makes it seem perhaps it is cheating to use $D(KP, KQ) \leq D(P, Q)$ here.)

Comment: Oh. Yes, not sure how to prove this with my hands tied then :)